# \captionsetup in classic thesis

Tags: captions, indentation, classicthesis

I am presently using classic thesis. In the figures and tables, the captions has default indentation, i.e. long captions 'hang' under the first line of the text. But I wish to have normal paragraph text as caption. So in the `classicthesis-config.tex` file I changed `\captionsetup{format=hang,font=small}` to `\captionsetup{format=default,font=small}`. But still I am getting hanging captions. What else should I modify? Here is a sample code.

```
    \documentclass[ oneside,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt
            ]{scrreprt}
    \input{classicthesis-config}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example_4}
    \caption[Tu duo titulo debitas latente]{A view of differnet objects in the world. The first flower indiacates its orientation about the sky A view of the obejects .}\label{fig:example}
  \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

This results in a caption hanging around the first line with indentation. [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `classicthesis-config.tex` file should be a skeleton for further personalization and in general should not be loaded as such. Can you prepare a small example of code showing the issue?

Comment: And where do you load the package? Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks egreg and Macro. I'll edit the post again to work with the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

File `classicthesis-config.tex` load package `caption` for which is set `\captionsetup{font=small}`. This you can change with new `\captionsetup{...}` placed after  `classicthesis-config.tex`. For example:

```
\captionsetup{format=plain, font=small, labelfont=bf}
```

will gives format similar to

[image]

For other desired caption layout see documentation of `caption` package. Complete example:

```
\documentclass[oneside, paper=a4, fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
\input{classicthesis-config}
\captionsetup{format=plain, font=small, labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption[Tu duo titulo debitas latente]{A view of differnet objects in the world. The first flower indiacates its orientation about the sky A view of the obejects .}\label{fig:example}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `classicthesis-config` isn't a package. The package is `classicthesis` which isn't loaded yet. It's a single tex file which has to be saved in your working directory. The file `classicthesis-config.tex` is part of the documentation. You can run `ls /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/latex/classicthesis`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, thank you for pointing me to wrong used term. Corrected.

Comment: I edited my comment. Using the file `classicthesis-config` doesn't mean that your are using `classicthesis` ;-)

Comment: It works! Came to know where I got wrong.

Comment: @Jerry, if answer is useful to you, you can vote for it and even accept it :)

Comment: How to reflect the changes in the caption style(\captionsetup{format=plain, font=small, labelfont=bf})in the List of Figures? Essentially, I want the same captioning style in the List Figures and in individual figures.

Comment: For list of figures styles are defined separately. Since I don't use `scrreprt` document class, I don't know, how this is manage in it. I'm pretty sure, that this is described in documentation of it.